# Do I need to serialize access to class members when all methods are async

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await, thread-safety

I have a rather elementary question. I have converted code to be fully async from  end to end. In the past, I have worked with `Parallel.ForEach()` and use `lock(synLock){}` to serialize access to class variables. In the code below I am using a normal foreach loop and during each iteration my plan was to buildup _Context for various functions to access and modify during the processing. So my question is -> Would `_Context` be considered thread safe in a way that I would not have to maintain locks for updates?

```
protected ServiceWorkContext _Context = new ServiceWorkContext();

protected async Task PerformServiceWork()
{
    var orderedProcessingConfigItems = await GetConfiguirationsForProcessingAsync((int)ReportDataGroupEnum.ReportData);

    foreach (var config in orderedProcessingConfigItems)
    {
        var databases = await GetDatabasesAsync();

        _Context.ClientDatabase = databases.Where(p => p.ClientDatabaseID == config.ClientDatabaseID).FirstOrDefault();
        _Context.LogBatchID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        await ProcessOneAsync();    // Is _Context safe to use here
        await ProcessTwoAsync();    // and here
        await ProcessThreeAsync();  // and here

    }
}
```

Comment: No. But you need to do that when the access is concurrent. Current and asynchronous are not the same thing.

Comment: Are multiple threads calling `PerformServiceWork`?

Comment: If `_Context` would be local to your `PerformServiceWork` then it would thread-safe. Since it is a class level member it is not thread-safe, because other methods could access it as well while `PerformServiceWork` is running.

Comment: @tymtam - Yes but that is handled by an entirely different orchestration. Each instance of this class is thread safe from that aspect.

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks. after thinking about it for a bit, I think it will be ok. PerformServiceWork() is the only entry into the class and the _Context changes per loop and the 3 main calls are ordered. The rest of the methods are private and consumed only by the the 3 methods in the loop. I use the _Context to avoid sending 5 objects as formal parameters to a multitude of private class methods.